# Помогите с пунктуацией (2)

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, цитата

Помогите с пунктуацией:

**Но откуда она взялась? Многих всегда мучал этот вопрос.**

Answer (score 1):

Возможны различные варианты, в зависимости от контекста. Вот некоторые из них.

**Но откуда она взялась? Многих всегда мучал этот вопрос.**

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> В то же мгновение он обратил внимание на лопатку, подняв ее, повернул, увидел срез и подумал, что это, должно быть, лопатка Гусева… **Откуда она взялась?** Эта догадка, разумеется, требовавшая подтверждения, вывела его из состояния, в каком он пребывал после получения письма. [Владимир Богомолов. Момент истины (В августе сорок четвертого...) (1973)]

**Но откуда она взялась ― многих всегда мучал этот вопрос.**

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> Но **откуда она взялась** ― вопрос, на который ученые пытались ответить. [Борис Ляпунов. Неоткрытая планета (1963)]

Обратите внимание на то, что "мучал" ― менее употребимая, разговорная форма, "мучил" ― нейтральный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример можно оформить двояко.

"Но откуда она взялась?" — многих всегда мучал этот вопрос.

Если прямая речь начинается с абзаца.

— Но откуда она взялась? — многих всегда мучал этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Возможны такие варианты оформления:

1) Два предложения:

**Но откуда она взялась? Многих всегда мучил этот вопрос.**

В этом варианте сохраняется вопросительная интонация.

2) БСП со значением изъяснения:

**Но откуда она взялась — этот вопрос всегда мучил многих.**

Вопросительная интонация отсутствует, в предложение желательно изменить порядок слов.